# When is a question/answer considered to have too many hyperlinks?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I'm [curious](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/curiosity-killed-the-cat.html) as to what's considered "overkill", in terms of the number of [hyperlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink) per Q/A.  Is there such thing as too many hyperlinks?  Is a [significant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) amount of hyperlinks considered [spam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam)? [To what extent](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1459490) do hyperlinks become a [nuisance](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/nuisance)?

What can I do to ensure that the questions I ask or the answers I write have enough links to convince other users it's a "research done, enough proof" sort of deal?

Comment: I can't give you any rules, but I can tell an over-hyperlinked post when I see it. As you no doubt intended, yours is one of them :)

Comment: If I post too many links (I like to back up my posts with proof), does it become too much information then?  Is there a limit?

Comment: As Pekka says, this is a judgment call. Proposing an exact number would only invite endless bickering (if twelve is okay, then why not thirteen? why not eleven?) or even abuse (cue every post having exactly twelve links which people then have to wade through to make sure none of them is spam).

Comment: So, if no limit is imposed, does it matter how much proof I have for my answers? Do all links have to be hyperlinks (if I reference a wikia or something)

Comment: What kinds of non-hyperlink links were you considering?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Links should be *relevant*. That's really all that matters. They should add value to a majority of the anticipated audience of your text.

Wikipedia links may make sense for really, really exotic terms that the reader is very unlikely to know. In that case, linking to the article's definition is a convenience and you highlight that it's an exotic term that you are using for a specific reason. 
Hyperlinking doesn't make sense for everyday terms, though.

It's a judgement call. Use common sense.

> I don't want my answers to seem like "no research done, no proof, not an acceptable answer"

Adding *relevant* sources and proof to your answer is *always* going to be okay. Maybe show some examples of what you are worried about.

Comment: You know, this answer would be so much better with a link or two ;)